# How do I format a number in C# with commas and decimals?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a number with a variable number of digits after the decimal point.  I want to format the number with commas and all decimal numbers.

For example: 42,023,212.0092343234

If I use ToString("N") I get only 2 decimals, ToString("f") gives me all decimals no commas.  How do I get both?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure (and unable to test right now) but would something like this work?

```
"#,##0.################"
```

Comment: Best so far, it works as long as the decimals aren't longer than the number of #'s... I was hoping to avoid this option but if its the only way.....

Comment: Good call. I say this is the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
string.Format("{0:#,##0.############}", value);
```

will give you up to 12 decimal places.

There is not a custom format specifier for "all following digits", so something like this will be closest to what you want.

Note too that you're limited by the precision of your variable.  A `double` only has 15-16 digits of precision, so as your left-hand side gets bigger the number of decimal places will fall off.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: Looking at the [MSDN documentation on the `System.Double` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx), I see this:

> By default, a Double value contains 15
>   decimal digits of precision, although
>   a maximum of 17 digits is maintained
>   internally.

So I think [pdr's on to something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311913/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-c-with-commas-and-decimals/3312078#3312078), actually. Just do this:

```
// As long as you've got at least 15 #s after the decimal point,
// you should be good.
value.ToString("#,#.###############");
```

---

Here's an idea:

```
static string Format(double value)
{
    double wholePart = Math.Truncate(value);
    double decimalPart = Math.Abs(value - wholePart);
    return wholePart.ToString("N0") + decimalPart.ToString().TrimStart('0');
}
```

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(Format(42023212.0092343234));
```

Output:

```
42,023,212.00923432409763336
```

Ha, well, as you can see, this gives imperfect results, due (I think) to floating point math issues. Oh well; it's an option, anyway.

Comment: That would probably work, but I'd like to get a format string that I can give to a Grid Control, or anything else that understands .Net formatting so it can do the formatting for me and I can just give it the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ToString("N2")`

Comment: That only displays the last 2 decimals, I want it to display all of them but the number of decimals will vary from 0-?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this

`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0,0.00}")]`

Answer (score -1):

Here is the way somewhat to reach to your expectation...

```
decimal d = 42023212.0092343234M;

NumberFormatInfo nfi  = (NumberFormatInfo) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();

nfi.NumberDecimalDigits= (d - Decimal.Truncate(d)).ToString().Length-2;

Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("N",nfi));
```

For more detail about NumberFormatInfo.. look at MSDN ..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx

Comment: Probably because you're doing a double-cast to string.